# Fuse two vector representations with different shapes

Tags: pytorch

I have a vector representation with shape `[32, 80, 789]` and another vector representation with shape `[32, 256]`. I am trying to build a model that can fuse these two representations. Fusing them can be just their concatenation fed into a linear layer, but for that I need the second vector (`[32, 256]`) to be of shape `[32, 80, 256]`. I can then match their last dimension with another linear layer. Do you have any idea what kind of layer can I use to achieve this? Do you think an `unsqueeze` followed by a repeat will be a good solution? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `unsqueeze` followed by `repeat` will work.

```py
a = torch.ones(32, 80, 786)

b = torch.ones(32, 256)

b_1 = b.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, 80, 1)

c = torch.cat([a, b_1], axis=-1)

c.size()
# Out[16]: torch.Size([32, 80, 1042])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that practically it does the job, but repeating a representation N times across a dimension does not seem to me like a great solution. Or is it? Do you have any intuition on the practical implications of fusing like this? Will the following layers be robust to this fusion or will this just add noise?